# Multiple Nested Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have SectionInfo model which is related to Projects with ForeignKey and a Section2 model which is related to SectionInfo with OneToOneField. How can i access Section2 data direclty in Projects Serializer.

**models.py**

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    p_name_full = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    p_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)

class SectionInfo(models.Model):
    p_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sec_info', db_column='p_id')
    s_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    s_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column='type')
    s_length = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Section2(models.Model):
    info_id = models.OneToOneField('rsa.SectionInfo', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sec_2', db_column='info_id')
    s_cbRestrictionEnd_1 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    s_cbReflector_1 = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ProjectListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    sec_2 = Section2Serializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        depth = 2
        model = Projects
        fields = [
            'p_name',
            'p_name_full',
            'p_creation_date',
            'sec_2',
        ]

class Section2Serializer(ModelSerializer):
    sec_info = SectionInfoSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        depth = 2
        model = Section2
        fields = [
            'sec_info',
            'sec_ques',
            's_cbRestrictionEnd_1',
            's_cbReflector_1',
       ]

class SectionInfoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = SectionInfo
            fields = [
            's_name',
            's_type',
            's_length',
           ]
```

This shows the following error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `sec_2` on serializer `ProjectListSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Projects` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Projects' object has no attribute 'sec_2'.

Comment: Projects class and Section2 are not related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Projects class and Section2 are not directly related to each other. 
remove 'sec_2' and include 'sec_info' in the project serializer and then use

```
sec_2 = Section2Serializer(many=True)
fields = [...., 'sec_2']
```

in the SectionInfoSerializer.